# Post request is returning {} when accessing req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, post

I have been through numerous questions, none can quite help my situation.

On one page I have 2 forms, each `method="post"` that are going to different routes.  The first form works fine and the `req.body` populates as expected.  The second form returns an empty object upon accessing `req.body`.

I am using body-parser, which is why the first form works correctly, so what is wrong with my second form?

The server code (or the important bits):

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/upload", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
  let cat = req.body.categories; //returns element named "categories" as expected
   //this post request works

res.redirect("/upload#upload");
});


app.post("/delete", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)    //returns "{}"
    res.status(204).send();
})
```

The markup (also just the important bits):

```
//the working form
  <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <select id="categories" name="categories" class="btn dropdown-toggle">
            <option class="dropdown-item" value="Photography">Photography</option>
            <option class="dropdown-item" value="Painting">Painting</option>
            <option class="dropdown-item" value="Drawing">Drawing</option>
            <option class="dropdown-item" value="Digital">Digital</option>
       </select>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info"><i class="fas fa-upload"></i>Upload</button>
  </form>


//the form that is not working
  <form action="/delete" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <select id="medium" name="medium" class="btn dropdown-toggle" onchange="onChange()">
              <option id="blank" class="drodown-item" value="placeholder"></option>
              <option class="dropdown-item" value="photos">Photography</option>
              <option class="dropdown-item" value="paintings">Painting</option>
              <option class="dropdown-item" value="drawings">Drawing</option>
              <option class="dropdown-item" value="digitals">Digital</option>
         </select>
       <button name="button" type=submit class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Remove Artwork</button>
  </form>
```

So why would one work and not the other?  Is it because both forms are on the same page?  I have different routes to handle the different requests, so I don't see why.  Also, it would seem that body-parser is set up correctly since the other form (and the rest of the app) is working as expected.  Lastly, you can see I have several named elements in my form, so I didn't just forget them.

Many other questions have led to those being the answer, but not the case for me.

Comment: try removing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the delete (since you wouldn't uploading a file when you delete) - can't see why that would make a difference, but ... body-parser  documentation specifically states it doesn't handle multipart bodies - so perhaps `upload.single("image")` is helping the upload

Comment: I can't believe it but that worked.  Such a silly oversight.  If you want to post that as the official answer I will mark it correct.

Comment: I would, but I don't understand why upload works, unless it's the `upload.single("image")` middleware that is parsing the body correctly

Comment: I just mean that removing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` worked.  The `upload.single` is for multer to process the images to be uploaded, so it is not relevant.

Comment: @Barmar - I mentioned that :p

Comment: So you're using `multer` but didn't show it in the question?

Comment: Didn't seem relevant.  Trying to give minimal code in my examples.  Also using a lot of other middleware, but as I said the first comment was correct.

Comment: @PsiKai - nothing wrong with answering your own question, I can't find the right wording to be honest :p